# SMTP Client - Send hidden information that can come back in a reply

Tags: node.js, smtp

[I am using the `nodemailer` SMTP node module](http://www.nodemailer.com/docs/smtp), a simple way to send emails through SMTP.

I am using this to send out text messages to various cell carriers, which will allow you to send a text message for free via email. An example email, which will text the Sprint phone (310) 987-6543:

```
3109876543@messaging.sprintpcs.com
```

These are all going out through one SMTP email address. This means all text replies from someone's phone will channel back to my email address.

A lot of people send these texts. I want to route the reply text back to the right person, using my own server side code.

The problem is distinguishing where the text came from. Ideally I could hide my own primary key ID for the sender in some sort of SMTP header, which would arrive at the recipients phone and come straight back in their text reply.

I don't really know anything about SMTP or email protocols - is this possible?

#### edit

As given in each of the answers below, in better email servers you can address to an email address as well as an extension to that address, such as:

```
// original email
sms-service@mysite.com

// extension
sms-service+a6e1087b@mysite.com
```

This would be a correct answer and would solve my problem, if only this worked in Exchange Server, which is the email server I am using. I don't know if there is a way to enable this or any other workaround.

Comment: I presume the subject line doesn't come back to you in the response?

Comment: No - not uniformly via phone sms messages from all vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange server doesn't support plus addressing natively but it is possible do achieve this with a custom MTA, e.g. http://durdle.com/regexcatchall/

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/195276/does-exchange-support-plussed-users-e-g-mynamespamexample-com-or-a-similar

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches that you might be able to use:

### Unique from addresses

You could you use unique "from" or "reply-to" address for each each message (or for each recipient). For example "sms-service+a6e1087b@mysite.com". In that example, the hex would be a unique identifier that can be mapped to the conversation in your database.

Gmail supports such a scheme: emails targeted to [foo]+[whatever]@gmail.com will be delivered to [foo]@gmail.com and the receiver will know also get the [whatever] back. (more on this http://lifehacker.com/144397/instant-disposable-gmail-addresses)

### Identify the user, not the conversation

One option is to not identify the conversation, but identify the phone number the reply comes back from instead. In many cases, the number from where the SMS reply was sent back from is enough to connect that message to the conversation. I'm sure the SMS gateway you're using will provide you with the number from where the reply came from.

### Commercial SMS gateway

You can also opt to use a commercial SMS gateway (smsglobal.com comes to mind, though there are many others). These services have well defined APIs for sending a receiving replies. This naturally comes at a price, though. But along with the price, you do get more confidence as to the reliability of the service. A free SMS gateway might get shut down without much warning.

Comment: Thanks. Approach 1 above is the only viable approach for me, and this is the type of thing I was looking for. The email server I use is unfortunately Exchange Server (I hate you, Microsoft), and upon testing this, it didn't recognize `foobar+myemail@myexchangeserver.net` - the email just got spat right back to me. Do you know if it is possible to implement this in exchange server?

Comment: And my last question: is there a formal for this unique identifier so I can google around on it and not just be a help vampire? Thanks.

Comment: @dc2 I revised my answer but it seems stuck waiting for approval. To summarize, there's another choice to transfer the unique id along the "From" or "Reply-To" address. By spec, these fielda may inclyde the user name, e.g. "SMS Message 6a108fc <foo@address.com>". If the SMS gateway respects this name and uses it when sending the SMS replies, you can identify the original conversation this way.

Comment: Clever - let me try that.

Comment: @dc2 it's often called "plus addressing" or "sub-addressing"

Answer (score 1):

This common problem is traditionally implemented using the semantics of `From:` and `Reply-To:` headers of e-mails. This is in fact not (directly) related to SMTP, but rather to ARPA network text messages.

RFC 5322 is the current specification of these messages. It states:

> When the "Reply-To:" field is present, it indicates the address(es) to which the author of the message suggests that replies be sent.  In the absence of the "Reply-To:" field, replies SHOULD by default be sent to the mailbox(es) specified in the "From:" field unless otherwise specified by the person composing the reply.

So you simply need to encode the information you need into the `Reply-To:` header. Since you mention your own server-side code, you might be running an SMTP server yourself. In this case, you can put any address that will be routed to your SMTP server and encode the *right person*'s address there.

Alternatively, if you rely on another SMTP server, you might want to use aliases. Postfix, and mail services such as GMail, typically allow address extensions, i.e. addresses of the form `user+foo@domain.com`, and you can encode the necessary information in the address extension.

For example, let's say that `alice@domain.com` wants to send a text to Sprint phone (310) 987-6543 through your service, you could send an e-mail to `3109876543@messaging.sprintpcs.com` with:

```
Reply-To: alice%40domain.com@yourservice.com
```

Alternatively:

```
Reply-To: yourservice+alice%40domain.com@gmail.com
```

This will allow you to route the reply properly by looking at the destination of the reply e-mail.

Comment: Thanks and this is the exact type of thing I was looking for - I have never heard of this before. The email server I use is unfortunately Exchange Server (I hate you, Microsoft), and upon testing this, it didn't recognize foobar+myemail@myexchangeserver.net - the email just got spat right back to me. Do you know if it is possible to implement this in exchange server?